# Yellow Small Circle Detection Using GoCV

Tags: opencv, go

I'm trying to detect circle with checkmark with variety of colours. What I want to detect is yellow with white checkmark, and in the future red circle with x mark. [image: one warning one normal][image: few warning few normal][image: lots of standby few normal]

What I've been trying so far are these codes below. This one using Hough Circles method.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "image"
    "image/color"
    "os"

    "gocv.io/x/gocv"
)

func DetectCircles() {
    if len(os.Args) < 2 {
        fmt.Println("How to run:\n\tfind-circles [imgfile]")
        return
    }

    filename := os.Args[1]

    grey_window := gocv.NewWindow("grey window")
    grey_window.MoveWindow(600, 0)
    window := gocv.NewWindow("detected circles")
    defer grey_window.Close()
    defer window.Close()

    original_img := gocv.IMRead(filename, gocv.IMReadColor)
    defer original_img.Close()

    img := gocv.NewMat()
    defer img.Close()

    gocv.CvtColor(original_img, &img, gocv.ColorBGRToGray)

    gocv.MedianBlur(img, &img, 5)

    circles := gocv.NewMat()
    defer circles.Close()

    gocv.HoughCirclesWithParams(
        img,
        &circles,
        gocv.HoughGradient,
        1, // dp
        // float64(img.Rows()/8), // minDist
        26,
        200, // param1
        48,  // param2
        0,   // minRadius
        0,   // maxRadius
    )

    green := color.RGBA{0, 255, 0, 0}
    red := color.RGBA{255, 0, 0, 0}

    for i := 0; i < circles.Cols(); i++ {
        v := circles.GetVecfAt(0, i)
        // if circles are found
        if len(v) > 2 {
            x := int(v[0])
            y := int(v[1])
            r := int(v[2])

            gocv.Circle(&original_img, image.Pt(x, y), r, green, 2)
            gocv.Circle(&original_img, image.Pt(x, y), 2, red, 3)
        }
    }

    for {
        window.IMShow(original_img)

        if window.WaitKey(10) >= 0 {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

With some adjustment, I manage to detect some bigger circles like these.
[image: bigger circle detection]

But still no luck when I try with smaller circle.
[image: smaller circle detection]

These are the codes I wrote to isolate the colour. What I did was adding some colour mask from and to certain HSV range.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "image"
    "image/color"
    "os"

    "gocv.io/x/gocv"
)

func DetectCircles2() {
    if len(os.Args) < 2 {
        fmt.Println("How to run:\n\tgo run . [imgfile]")
        return
    }

    filename := os.Args[1]

    window := gocv.NewWindow("detected colors")
    window2 := gocv.NewWindow("end result")
    window3 := gocv.NewWindow("lower bound")
    window4 := gocv.NewWindow("upper bound")
    window2.MoveWindow(600, 0)
    window3.MoveWindow(0, 600)
    window4.MoveWindow(600, 600)
    defer window.Close()
    defer window2.Close()
    defer window3.Close()
    defer window4.Close()

    img := gocv.IMRead(filename, gocv.IMReadColor)
    defer img.Close()

    original_image := img.Clone()
    defer original_image.Close()

    gocv.MedianBlur(img, &img, 3)

    hsv_img := gocv.NewMat()
    defer hsv_img.Close()

    // yellow := gocv.NewScalar(0, 255, 255, 0)
    // yellow_mat := gocv.NewMatFromScalar(yellow, gocv.MatTypeCV8UC3)
    // gocv.CvtColor(yellow_mat, &yellow_mat, gocv.ColorBGRToHSV)
    // hsv := gocv.Split(yellow_mat)
    // fmt.Printf("H: %d S: %d V: %d\n", hsv[0].GetUCharAt(0, 0), hsv[1].GetUCharAt(0, 0), hsv[2].GetUCharAt(0, 0))

    gocv.CvtColor(img, &hsv_img, gocv.ColorBGRToHSV)
    img_rows, img_cols := hsv_img.Rows(), hsv_img.Cols()

    // lb1 := gocv.NewMatWithSizeFromScalar(gocv.NewScalar(0.0, 208.0, 94.0, 0.0), img_rows, img_cols, gocv.MatTypeCV8UC3)
    // ub1 := gocv.NewMatWithSizeFromScalar(gocv.NewScalar(179.0, 255.0, 255.0, 0.0), img_rows, img_cols, gocv.MatTypeCV8UC3)
    lb1 := gocv.NewMatWithSizeFromScalar(gocv.NewScalar(20.0, 50.0, 50.0, 0.0), img_rows, img_cols, gocv.MatTypeCV8UC3)
    ub1 := gocv.NewMatWithSizeFromScalar(gocv.NewScalar(40.0, 255.0, 255.0, 0.0), img_rows, img_cols, gocv.MatTypeCV8UC3)

    lb2 := gocv.NewMatWithSizeFromScalar(gocv.NewScalar(155.0, 100.0, 100.0, 0.0), img_rows, img_cols, gocv.MatTypeCV8UC3)
    ub2 := gocv.NewMatWithSizeFromScalar(gocv.NewScalar(180.0, 255.0, 255.0, 0.0), img_rows, img_cols, gocv.MatTypeCV8UC3)

    lower_bound := gocv.NewMat()
    upper_bound := gocv.NewMat()
    color_isolated_img := gocv.NewMat()
    circles := gocv.NewMat()
    defer lower_bound.Close()
    defer upper_bound.Close()
    defer color_isolated_img.Close()
    defer circles.Close()

    gocv.InRange(hsv_img, lb1, ub1, &lower_bound)
    gocv.InRange(hsv_img, lb2, ub2, &upper_bound)

    gocv.AddWeighted(lower_bound, 1.0, upper_bound, 1.0, 0.0, &color_isolated_img)
    gocv.GaussianBlur(color_isolated_img, &color_isolated_img, image.Pt(9, 9), 2, 2, gocv.BorderDefault)

    gocv.HoughCirclesWithParams(
        color_isolated_img,
        &circles,
        gocv.HoughGradient,
        1,
        float64(color_isolated_img.Rows()/8),
        100,
        20,
        0,
        0,
    )

    green := color.RGBA{0, 255, 0, 0}

    for i := 0; i < circles.Cols(); i++ {
        v := circles.GetVecfAt(0, i)
        fmt.Println(v)
        if len(v) > 2 {
            x := int(v[0])
            y := int(v[1])
            r := int(v[2])

            gocv.Circle(&original_image, image.Pt(x, y), r, green, 2)
        }
    }

    for {
        // window.IMShow(color_isolated_img)
        window2.IMShow(original_image)
        window3.IMShow(lower_bound)
        window4.IMShow(upper_bound)

        if window.WaitKey(10) >= 0 {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result. Code above only manage to detect one red circle (it's supposed to be two) and one yellow circle.
[image: circle with colour masking]

I've been trying to convert contour detection written in python only to stumble to confusing gocv API. I'm tagging gocv and opencv in hope these two communities would help me to properly detect small colourful circles. Any advice will be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: [Template matching](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html) with a template of the icon you are looking for should help here. The idea is to locate a smaller image on a bigger image. Now, because there is other icon there with the same image content but different color (the green circle with check), you would need a way of figuring out if the icon you just located is yellow or green. Once located, you could get the mean color of the icon, for example.

Comment: @stateMachine that's an interesting idea. I'll give it a try. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did was I installing another library that's called [gcv](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/vcaesar/gcv) by vcaesar. There was a method called FindAllImg and what I need just provide two image, one is the source image, in my case a screenshot, and the other is a template image that needed to be searched in the screenshot.